# Material UI - transition animation between dark and light theme/palette?

Tags: material-ui, themes, transition

I currently have a toggle to switch between dark and light theme and it is working perfectly.

I have it set up in this shape:

```
const dark = createTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
    primary: {
      main: MYCOLORS.dback,
    },
  },
});

const light = createTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "light",
    primary: {
      main: "yellow",
    },
  },
});

function App() {
  const [darkTheme] = useAtom(darkThemeAtom); // useAtom is just a simple state lib not that relevant to this question
  const appliedTheme = createTheme(darkTheme ? dark : light);

  return (
    <>
      <ThemeProvider theme={appliedTheme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <MyComponentA />
        <MyComponentB />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

My question is, how do I apply a transition effect between the dark and light theme across all my components?

If it's just css then I could simply do this: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp...

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hey! Have you found the solution?